# Transformation of Random Variable - Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, references

Let $X$ be one observation from a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ population .  What is the distribution of norm of $X$, i.e., $|X|$ ?

#### My attempt :

$$f_X(x;0,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}; -\infty<x<\infty$$

Then i  have stumbled.

Also, is random variable and observation identical terminology as it is mentioned $X$ be  observation .

Comment: You are along the right lines. You can treat observation and random variable as synonymous in this context. Given that X is symmetric about 0 that might give you a clue about the distribution of |X|

Comment: What does your answer give as the density at $|x|=-1$? what should it be?

Comment: You just have to double the Right branch and nullify the left branch

Answer (score 9):

Since this is self-study I will give you a hint.

$F_{|X|} = P(|X|<x) = P(-x<X<x) = F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$ where $F$ indicates the CDF of the appropriate random variable. Since we know the CDF of a normal random variable, $X$, we now know the CDF the absolute value of $X$. Differentiating will give us the PDF.

Comment: This answer is good for general normal distribution but is overkill for distribution symmetric about 0. There is a very simple solution in this case.

Comment: Agreed! But I personally find this the easiest solution to understand which makes it valuable for self-study. And the generality of the solution to non symmetric random variables also makes it valuable.

Comment: @tristan Your quibble about TrynnaDoStat's answer would be more creditable if you had posted only "good hints" towards the solution in [your own answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141598/6633). +1 to him.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I wasn't quibbling with the very good and general answer given by TrynnaDoStat but my feeling was that if I'd set this as a self-study question I'd be expecting students to notice the shortcut on this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give you some good hints towards the simple solution:

1. The distribution for $Y=|X|$ must be 0 for $Y<0$.
2. As $X$ is symmetric about 0 we know that $f_X(-x)=f_X(x)$.
3. $Y$ can take the value $y\ge 0$ if $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Hopefully that will get you on your way.

Comment: What does Point #3 mean?

Comment: It means that you look at $f_X(-y)$ and $f_X(y)$ to calculate $f_Y(y)$ and from #2 you work out that $f_X(-y)=f_X(y)$ therefore $f_Y(y)=2 f_X(y)$. Sorry that was apparently not the good hint I thought it was.